# difference between "->" and "." operator in C language (struct)

Tags: c, struct

I' just got started in learning struct in c language.
i Thought "->" and "." were equivalent but i get the following error when using "->" instead of ".":
*invalid type argument of '->' (have 'struct item')*

Comment: *i thought "->" and "." were equivalent* is it what your C book teached you? If yes, read it again.

Comment: I don't think this Question is a bad one. 3 Down votes and only one comment? If you find this Question bad, why someone gives an Answer to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a->b` is short for `(*a).b`.

There is no difference between `a->b` and `(*a).b`. There is a difference between `(*a).b` and `a.b`, of course - which is that the `*` dereferences `a` first (which must be a pointer or an array).